# Edits in wpf window don't update Observable object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Why do edits in my child window not affect the collection which I'm directly modifying from my main view models data context? When i click properties...it opens a seconds window where users can change the names of the people in the collection. However when i reopen the properties window Doug's name will be set back to default. I plan on making it possible for users to add/remove people from within this window as well. I'm a bit perplexed on why it wouldn't directly change and affect the bound data.

**Main Window**

[image]

**Child Window**

[image]
[image]

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Person> crowd;
        public ObservableCollection<Person> Crowd
        {
            get { return crowd ?? (crowd = new ObservableCollection<Person>()); }
            set { Set(ref crowd, value); }
        }

        private ICommand mainWindowCommand;
        public ICommand MainWindowCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return mainWindowCommand ?? (mainWindowCommand = new RelayCommand<CommandTargets>(ExecuteCommand));
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteCommand(CommandTargets parameter)
        {
            switch (parameter)
            {
                case CommandTargets.EditProperties:
                    PropertiesView PropertiesWindow = new PropertiesView();
                    PropertiesWindow.Show();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Crowd.Add(new Person("Doug"));
        }

    }

    public enum CommandTargets
    {
        EditProperties,
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Person( string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }

    class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecuteHandler;
        private readonly Action<T> _executeHandler;

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeHandler)
            : this(executeHandler, null)
        { }

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeHandler, Func<T, bool> canExecuteHandler)
        {
            _canExecuteHandler = canExecuteHandler;
            _executeHandler = executeHandler;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecuteHandler != null ? _canExecuteHandler((T)parameter) : true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _executeHandler((T)parameter);
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="250"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Menu.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MainWindowCommand}"/>
                </Style>
            </Menu.Resources>

            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Properties..." CommandParameter="{x:Static local:CommandTargets.EditProperties}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**PropertiesView.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.PropertiesView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PropertiesView" Height="300" Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0" 
                 x:Name="ItemList"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Crowd, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 SelectionMode="Single"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Name: " VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Try to set: `Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: That does not resolve it either. Try editing the name of Person. it doesn't stick still even with the changes you suggested.

Comment: You seem to set two different instances of `MainWindowViewModel` for each window. Edits are done on different object instances and is discarded when window is closed.

Comment: How do i fix that in this case then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different instances of the view model. You'll need to share the same instance for the editing to work.

```
private void ExecuteCommand(CommandTargets parameter)
    {
        switch (parameter)
        {
            case CommandTargets.EditProperties:
                PropertiesView PropertiesWindow = new PropertiesView();
                PropertiesWindow.DataContext=this;  //<----------- add this line 
                PropertiesWindow.Show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because each PropertiesView is using its own instance of the MainWindowViewModel so the two Views are referring to different ObservableCollections

I think the affect you are going for can be seen by making the private crowd member variable static.

```
private static ObservableCollection<Person> crowd;
```